# My search form is redirecting to the homepage. How to solve?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, search

Everytime when I try to search on my website, it keeps returning to the homepage. I have a search form though, built-in with my theme. Can't find the problem. Can you help me?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="content">
    <?php tie_breadcrumbs(); ?>

    <div class="page-head">
        <h2 class="page-title">
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'tie' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?>
            <?php else : ?>
            <?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'tie' ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </h2>
        <div class="stripe-line"></div>
    </div>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'search' );    ?>
        <?php if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) tie_pagenavi(); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <div id="post-0" class="post not-found post-listing">
            <div class="entry">
                <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.', 'tie' ); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

This is the website: http://plugr.nl

Addition: The HTML

```
    <?php if(tie_get_option( 'top_right' ) == 'search'): ?>
                <div class="search-block">
                    <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/">
                        <button class="search-button" type="submit" value="<?php if( !$is_IE ) _e( 'Search' , 'tie' ) ?>"></button> 
                        <input type="text" id="s" name="s" value="<?php _e( 'Search...' , 'tie' ) ?>" onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php _e( 'Search...' , 'tie' ) ?>') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '<?php _e( 'Search...' , 'tie' ) ?>';}"  />
                    </form>
                </div><!-- .search-block /-->
```

Comment: Why all those opening and closing tags?

Comment: Don't know, theme-default.

Comment: Oh, this is not your code. Smells like Wordpress-code, isn't it?

Comment: Ja, dat is waar Marcel ;-)

Comment: Look at the "action" of your HTML "<form..." tag

Comment: Can you show the HTML?

Comment: That's the weird thing. This code is in search.php. There isn't a search-form.php. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: It's about this website: http://plugr.nl

Comment: just write action="search.php" if you want to redirect to that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this search URL is what your template is expecting:
http://plugr.nl/?s=waar

Your form has code like:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://plugr.nl/">
    <input type="text" name="inputBox" placeholder="Typ wat je zoekt en druk op enter">
</form>
```

Change the input name to "s" and see what that does for you.

You might need to grep through the files in your template to find where this form is actually generated. Nested template files will not show up in the wordpress GUI editor. It's also possible your search form is provided through a widget which the template depends on, so you might need to dig a little further.

Comment: I've added the HTML above. Maybe that'll help. I've changed the action to "" and "#", but it doesn't work.

Comment: See if your template has a search page in its collection of files. If so, redirect to it in the action. If not, you might need to follow the following tutorial http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page

Comment: I think what you had was actually correct. I found the wordpress theme site, and its search form posts back to itself. It's possible your search arguments aren't being provided correctly. This works: http://plugr.nl/?s=hello

Comment: When I type 'hello' in the search box, the URL says: http://plugr.nl/?inputBox=hello. I don't get the /?s=hello.

Comment: yah, that's because the name is hardcoded to inputBox somewhere in your template. It might not be the file you found previously. Do a search for inputBox and try to replace that string once you find it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place "s" for the name value...name="s". Its a default setting for wordpress which will detect this variable for what kind of search you did.. /?s="whatever you searched for"